# What is the command for changing the parameters for the database information in a MySQL Settings file; in bash?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, bash, sed, configure

so basically, i am trying to configure wordpress by editing the parameters that hold the database parameters. But this is in a bash script that i have to use for launch. And I know i have to use sed but i'm not sure what the syntax is for editing the MySQL setting file. Here is what i got so far
________________________________________-
#configure wordpress

```
#moving into apache root direc where wordpress is 
cd /var/www/html
#using a thing
cp wp-config-sample.php php wp-config.php
#opening the text editor
nano wp-config.php

#this is me changing the parameters to what's in the 
#commas to configure wordpress in MySQL Setting file
sed s/define/'wordpress'/g
sed s/define/'wordpressuser'/g
sed s/define/'password'/g
```

---

and this is the format of the MySQL file with the parameters that i need it changed into. ie the wordpress the wordpressuer and password is what i need it to become

```
_________________________________________________
// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'wordpress');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'wordpressuser');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
___________________________________________________
```

Comment: You want to modify the file every time you launch?  It will modify the file only once, and never again, so why bother coding it?  Edit the file and be done.

Comment: i would love to, but i need to make a bash launch script that could configure a bunch of these. So i need to write a script that will configure it on a script

Comment: Ok.  You should show your original file and target file.  Then what you tried to modify  from one file to the other. What you show in the current question is like you are trying to replace "define" by "wordpress".  The 's/left/right/' in `sed` replaces the left part by the right part.  So if your line is `define('DB_NAME', 'NAMEVAR');`, the `sed` would be `'s/NAMEVAR/workpress/'.

Comment: this is actually very helpful thank you. Is it possible you can tell me what the original strings would be for the other two? like in define("DB_NAME', 'NAMEVAR'); the string was called NAMEVAR. Can you please tell me the other two? I can't seam to find it without having to reinstall wordpress and and all the other things before it to get the name. It would be very helpful

Comment: Actually, I do not know.  I just put something, but I do not have a clean wordpress installation to check.